# Join If ID exists Else return Other Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two existing table {`PeopleList`, `EmployeeList`}. My problem is how to create a query that joins the other table if a record exist in column but if not, returns the other record of the other column. To make it more clear, i will provide some informations (*dummy records*) below:

`PeopleList Table`

```
AutoInc_ID     EmployeeID     Name
============================================
1              EMP001         Mr. John Doe
2                             Mr. Johnsons
3                             Mrs. Jane Smith
4              EMP002         Mr. Juan Dela Cruz
```

and

`EmployeeList Table`

```
EmployeeID     AliasName     DepartmentID
============================================
EMP001         JDoe          DEP001
EMP002         JDCruz        DEP001
EMP003         Alien         DEP051
```

and the result i want is:

`Result Table`

```
AutoInc_ID     WorkerName
============================================
1              JDoe
2              Mr. Johnsons
3              Mr. Jane Smith
4              JDCruz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  PeopleList.AutoInc_ID,
  IFNULL(EmployeeList.AliasName,PeopleList.Name) as WorkerName
FROM
  PeopleList
  LEFT JOIN EmployeeList ON PeopleList.EmployeeID=EmployeeList.EmployeeID
;
```